# Flutter Access parent Scaffold from different dart file

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this:

```
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldkey,
        drawer: Menu(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
            child: Text('Dashboard'),
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, the `drawer: Menu()` is imported from another `menu.dart` file, which looks like this:

```
class Menu extends StatelessWidget {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> drawerKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      key: drawerKey,
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: new Text('My Text'),
            onTap: () {
              // On tap this, I want to show a snackbar.
              scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(showSnack('Error. Could not log out'));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With the above approach, I get

`NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.`

An easy solution is to tuck the entire `menu.dart` contents in the `drawer: ...` directly.

Another way I'm looking at is being able to reference the parent scaffold in order to display the snackbar.

How can one achieve that?

Why can't one even just call the snackbar from anywhere in Flutter and compulsorily it has to be done via the Scaffold? Just why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should try to avoid using `GlobalKey` as much as possible; you're almost always better off using `Scaffold.of` to get the ScaffoldState. Since your menu is below the scaffold in the widget tree, `Scaffold.of(context)` will do what you want.

The reason what you're attempting to do doesn't work is that you are creating two seperate GlobalKeys - each of which is its own object. Think of them as global pointers - since you're creating two different ones, they point to different things. And the state should really be failing analysis since you're passing the wrong type into your Drawer's `key` field...

If you absolutely have to use GlobalKeys for some reason, you would be better off passing the instance created in your outer widget into your `Menu` class as a member i.e. `this.scaffoldKey`, but this isn't recommended.

Using `Scaffold.of`, this is what your code would look like in the onTap function:

```
onTap: () {
  // On tap this, I want to show a snackbar.
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(showSnack('Error. Could not log out'));
},
```

Comment: Using any of that makes no difference in this instance though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370795/flutter-trying-to-fire-a-showmodalbottomsheet-mystery

Comment: what is the work around for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189547/flutter-snackbar-not-showing @rmtmckenzie

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by using builder widget you don't need to make separate GlobalKey or pass key as a parameter. Just wrap a widget to Builder widget

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Drawer(
  child: new ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Builder(builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
        return ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: new Text('My Text'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Scaffold.of(innerContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Added added into cart'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                action: SnackBarAction(label: 'UNDO', onPressed: () {}),
              ));
            }
            );
      })
    ],
  ),
);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your first question 
In other to reference the parent scaffold in the menu widget you can pass the `_scaffoldkey` to the menu widget as parameter and use `ScaffoldMessenger.of()` to show snackbar as  shown below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Root Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // App name
      title: 'Flutter SnackBar',
      // Theme
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Test(title: 'SnackBar'),
    );
  }
}
 

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? title;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Test({@required this.title});

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: widget._scaffoldkey,
        drawer: Menu(parentScaffoldkey:widget._scaffoldkey),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
            child: Text('Dashboard'),
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(text:"Home"),
              Tab(text:"About")
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Home"),
            Text("About")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Menu part as shown

```
class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  final parentScaffoldkey;
  
  Menu({this.parentScaffoldkey});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: new Text('My Text'),
            onTap: () {
              // On tap  show a snackbar.
             // ScaffoldMessenger will call the nearest Scaffold to show snackbar
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(this.parentScaffoldkey.currentContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text('Error. Could not log out')));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also,you have to call snackbar via Scaffold because it provides the SnackBar API and manages it